# React Native - Managing app.json based on the env

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a React Native app. So I found a great way to have multiple envs using [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv). Now I want to add Facebook login to my app. There is [configuration that is needed](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/#configure--appjson) and has to be set in app.json.

I would like to use a different Facebook app for my dev and my prod. How can I change fields in app.json based on my `.env` file, or is there a better way to manage this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your `package.json` has this

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:prod": "APP_ENV=prod npx react-native start",
  }
}
```

you add a `prestart:prod`, and it will automatically run before `start:prod`, in your `prestart:prod` modify your `app.json`, you can write a js file (lets name it prestart.js) to read the `app.json` parse it as a json, modify the field, then write that stringified json to `app.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:prod": "APP_ENV=prod npx react-native start",
    "prestart:prod": "node scripts/prestart.js",
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I will try it and tell you how it goes :) thanks

Comment: I'm a `react-native-dotenv` maintainer. If you have caching issues make sure to clear the cache using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project